# Converting PNG to Bitmap to Byte[] to store in SQL

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-bitmap

I'm trying to convert a PNG file into a Bitmap into a Byte[] so I can store the image in my SQL database.

Converting the PNG to a Bitmap.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; 

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.MyPicture, options)
```

Convert Bitmap to Byte[]

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

byte[] bArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Insert into database

```
MainViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(bArray);
myViewModel.insert(myEntity);
```

I'm Currently getting NullpointException, in the **b.compress** line of my code.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your bitmap is null because you have set `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true` and passing this options variable to `decodeResource()` function. Read [these docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)